# Vlookup to another worksheet as WorksheetFunction

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I can't get this code to work.

```
Worksheets("5200").Activate
Range("a1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("b1", ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Trial Balance").Range("B:I"), 8, False)
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to do, with sample data and desired outcome, what error you get, and on which line.

Comment: Unless you are looking for the string `b1` then you need to wrap that in `Range` so `Range("B1")`

Comment: Are you trying to make the formula on `A1` to be the `VLOOKUP`? If so you are not pointing to the right range element. Or are you just looking to have the result of the `VLOOKUP` in `A1`?

Comment: To complete @trincot comment, you should read : [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My problem is I never put range before ("b1"). Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`"b1"` is not a range. While I hesitate to recommend square-bracket-referencing, you could try it as,

```
Range("a1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([B1], ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Trial Balance").Range("B:I"), 8, False)
```

I believe it would be better as,

```
with Worksheets("5200")
  .Range("a1") = Application.VLookup(.Range("b1"), _
       .Parent.Worksheets("Trial Balance").Range("B:I"), 8, False)
end with
```